# Как спрятать уже созданные коммиты?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Случайно запушил - 4 коммита, как я могу спрятать эти коммиты? (Stash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коммиты уже запушены - лучший вариант - создать новый коммит, отменяющий изменения.

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD~0
git revert --no-commit HEAD~1
git revert --no-commit HEAD~2
git revert --no-commit HEAD~3
# или git revert --no-commit HEAD~4..HEAD
git commit -a -m "Revert of 4 commits"
git push
```

То же самое можно сделать с помощью checkout:

```
git checkout -f HEAD~4 -- . # восстановить состояние всех файлов в соответствие с коммитом на 4 позади головы ветки
git commit -a -m "Revert of 4 commits"
git push
```

*Вместо HEAD~4 лучше явно указать hashset нужного коммита*

---

Если же вы **абсолютно** уверены, что никто не получил ненужные ревизии, можете просто удалить их:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4 # Жёстко удалить 4 коммита
git push -f
```

Если терять вы их не хотите:

```
git reset HEAD~4 # Удалить 4 коммита из истории
git push -f
```

Все изменения в этом случае остануться в рабочей директории, вы можете увидеть их по `git status` и делать с ними, что угодно, `git stash`, например, или перекоммитить в другой конфигурации...

Можно также сохранить коммиты в прежней конфигурации в другой ветке.

```
git checkout -b temp_branch
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~4
git push -f
```